# can not login to custom ami

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to initiate an instance that is found here...

https://aws.amazon.com/amis/aws-tools

The instance is launched but when I try to login, I get the following message:

```
ssh -i oct9.pem root@ec2-50-16-125-42.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

If I launch a new instance using the built-in wizard, It works as expected with the same .pem key.

This AMI was working as expected till recently. I have used it before for a few instances. I would like to use this because it has several utilities pre-installed.

Comment: Can some one initiate an instance and check if this is really working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you produce a new image from a running instance, you end up getting locked out of the running instance. I'm not sure why, but you can then re-launch a new instance from the image you just created.

It's unclear whether or not this is the issue you're running into, though.